# Environment variables in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose with https://hub.docker.com/r/pottava/docker-webui/.

Here's my compose-file:

```
monit:
  image: pottava/docker-webui
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  volumes:
    - "${DOCKER_CERT_PATH}:/etc/docker-compose/cert"
  environment:
    - DOCKER_HOST
    - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/etc/docker-compose/cert
    - APP_LABEL_OVERRIDE_NAMES=com.docker.compose.service
    - APP_LABEL_FILTERS=com.docker.compose.service
```

I get the following error message:

> ERROR: for monit  Cannot create container for service monit: create .:
> volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric
> characters

I then tested the compose-file with providing a literal for ${DOCKER_CERT_PATH} and then the compose-file works.

This feels weird since I thought this is how environment variables are used in docker-compose.
Do I have an error somewhere?

Comment: What is the value of `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` in your environment? Your question doesn't show how you've verified that.

Comment: echo ${DOCKER_CERT_PATH} returns an empty string, but isn't the variable supposed to be set through the second list item under the environment key? If it's not, then what is the point of that?

Comment: The `environment` key is for setting environment variables *inside the container*. To do what you're trying to do in the `volumes` section, you'll need to set the value in your local environment, or use a `.env` file.

Comment: Much appreciated.